# Cloud Foundry - updating to NGINX buildpack - 500 error during deploy

Tags: nginx, environment-variables, cloud-foundry, nginx-config, buildpack

I'm currently updating the cloud foundry buildpack for my angular application from the deprecated staticfile-buildpack-v2 to the NGINX buildpack.

I've been updating my nginx.conf with the updated syntax listed here:

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/nginx/

The build is passing and the app is being pushed to PCF, but cloud foundry is unable to find the application root and I receive a 500 error every time I go to the URL where it is being hosted.

Essentially what I'm asking is what is wrong with my nginx.conf file that is not allowing NGINX to find my app root.

I uploaded my nginx.conf, buildpack.yml, manifest.yml, and mime.types files here:

https://github.com/boldham31/buildpack-fix/tree/master

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `deprecated staticfile-buildpack-v2` -> I do not believe that is true. At least not at this time. The Staticfile buildpack serves a specific use case of hosting static files. It's more convenient for this because it will configure Nginx automatically for you. The Nginx buildpack on the other hand just provides you with Nginx and you need to configure it. Because you can configure it to do whatever you want, it can handle some use cases that the Staticfile buildpack cannot or cannot do well (so you could say certain use cases with Staticfile buildpack are depecated, but not the whole buildpack)

Comment: Your nginx.conf file still has embedded ruby in it. You need to remove all that. The nginx buildpack isn't running your config through `erb`. If you need that stuff, you'd have to run `erb` on your config file manually, perhaps in a `.profile` file.

Comment: Agreed, I think testing all of the scenarios has shown me that the staticfile_buildpack (the most recent version, as opposed to the older staticfile-buildpack-v2) provides the most value since it automatically configures nginx. My specific issue was applying the environment variables' values. But on PCF's end, as long as I set those values I should be good to go. I'll keep testing and report back, thanks for the clarifying comments.